# Alphanumeric range validation

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, range, alphanumeric

Is there a way where we can find a range in the given two alphanumeric strings and apply validation for an input field? The range can appear in any position within the alphanumeric values. Trying to implement this in angular typescript file.

Example:
For the range of 123-01N3W to 123-01N97W, 123-01N45W is in range.
12301N45W is not in range. (Missing hyphen element)
123-01N2W is not in range. (2 < 3)
123-01N98W is not in range. (98 > 97)

Answer (score 0):

create a custom validation

```
validationRange(min:string,max:string){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
       if (control.value)
       {
          const minInt=+(min.replace(/\D/gi,""))
          const maxInt=+(max.replace(/\D/gi,""))

          const valueInt=+(control.value.replace(/\D/gi,""))
          return valueInt>=minInt && valueInt<=maxInt?null:{range:"not in range"}
       }
    }
}

//you use

control=new FormControl(null,this.validationRange("123-01N3W","123-01N97W")
```

If you want that the min and max are not fixed (*), e.g. is from anothers formControls in the same formGroup you can

```
//your form is like
form=new FormGroup({
   min:new FormControl(null),
   max:new FormControl(null),
   value:new FormControl(null,this.validationRange())
})

validationRange(){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
       const form=(control.parent as FormGroup)
       if (form && control.value){
          const ctrlMax=form.get('max');
          const ctrlMin=form.get('min');
          if (ctrlMax && ctrlMin && ctrMax.value && ctrMin.value)
          {
               const ctrMin.value=+(min.replace(/\D/gi,""))
               const ctrMax.value=+(max.replace(/\D/gi,""))

               const valueInt=+(control.value.replace(/\D/gi,""))
               return valueInt>=minInt && valueInt<=maxInt?null:{range:"not in range"}
          }
      }
    }
}
```

But remember, when change "min" and "max" make a

```
  this.form.get('value').updateValueAndValidity()
```

e.g. in (blur) event

```html
      <form formGroup]="form">
       <input formControlName="min" (blur)="form.get('value').updateValueAndValidity()">
       <input formControlName="min" (blur)="form.get('value').updateValueAndValidity()">
       <input formControlName="value" >
      </form>
```

(*) when we create a custom form validation which depends from variables, we need take account that the value that get is the "actual" value of the variables. So if, this variables are from a call to an API, we need make the setValidation after we get the values